# Password visiblity Toggle in edittext is not working properly

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

When the password is visible then the **cross on eye icon** is not appear.How to put the cross sign when password is visible on the eye icon.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                android:textColorHint="#818893"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat">

                <EditText
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textWebPassword" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: What version of Support design library are you using?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0' @NikoAdrianusYuwono

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your support library to 25.1.0 there are some known issue with password toggle visibility in 24.x

Refer to these issues:

- [Password visibility toggle fails accessibility checks](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220599&q=component%3DSupport-Libraries%20-has%3Aenhancement%20attachments%3D0%20appcompat&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&start=100)
- [Password visibility toggle position error](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222307)
- [TextInputLayout Password Visibility State out of Sync](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224040)

Comment: Thankks @Niko Asrianus

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_linear_pwd_container_margin_top"
            android:background="@drawable/login_edittext_gradient"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_visibility"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="@string/login_password_title"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/login_edittext_left_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/login_edittext_left_padding"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/tab_text_color" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```